# Android: TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a question in regards to http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html Lots of issues are already discussed but this example only works for me if I in the onCreate() method do NOT use setContentView(R.layout.main); Why is that? What do I have to do if I want to mix a tab layout with other elements?

Thanks.
paradroid666

Comment: Could u post the content of your main.xml file?

Comment: And what happens when you DO use setContentView(R.layout.main)?

Comment: If i do it I get a force application shutdown.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:paddingTop="5dip">

Comment: <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></TabWidget>
  <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:paddingTop="5dip">
  </FrameLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

Comment: You should post the Logcat content too

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for finding this out. I had the problem, that my `TabActivity` showed the tab-bar but didn't show the content of the tabs/activities. After removing the `setContentView(R.layout.main)` in the `TabActivity` it now shows the tab-content.